# Display Errors only when I specify error_reporting Level

Tags: php

I've re-configured my Apache and now I want it to run in a better way.
To be more precise, I want to configure php.ini in such a manner that errors will only be displayed when I specify `error_reporting` so  by default they wouldn't be displayed. This is because I'm developing a platform and I want to see errors as I go, then stop them for showing without having to go through the php.ini hassle.

I tried `display_errors = Off` but that wouldn't display errors even after I specify error_reporting level.

Ideas ?

Comment: in my opinion use specific error message like `mysqli::$error` or `curl_error`. Otherwise you can get error like `error_get_last` [link](http://tr1.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php)

Comment: show all errors not recommended for a stable server

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should learn more about how you have to configurate your php.ini and know which command do what.

If you deactivate to display the errors there will be no errors displayed even if you set an error level.

But here is your answere: [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ini-set.php)

```
<?php
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
?>
```

with ini_set() during the execution of the script your options take action, after execution it is back to default.